# proof that addition multiplication and < are well defined on the Hyperreals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could someone please check my proof for showing addition, multiplication and < are well defined on the Hyperreal numbers.

Proof:

Suppose $$[a_n]=[b_n]$$ and $$[c_n]=[d_n]$$ where [] denotes the equivalence class. Let U denote a non-principal ultrafilter.Further let  A=$$ \{{n\in \mathbb N:a_n=b_n}\}$$ , B=$$\{{n\in \mathbb N: c_n=d_n}\}$$ then $$\{{n\in \mathbb N: a_nc_n=b_nd_n}\}=A\cap B$$ The same argument holds for addition.

For < suppose that $$[a_n]<[c_n]$$ and let G=$$\{{n\in \mathbb N: a_n<c_n}\} \in U$$. The set which $$b_n<c_n$$ contains $$G\cap A$$ and is thus in U. So $$[b_n]<[c_n]$$. Let H=$$\{{n\in \mathbb N: b_n<c_n}\}$$. Then the set for which $$b_n<d_n$$ contains $$H\cap B$$ and is therefore in U. Thus $$[b_n]<[d_n]$$.

Comment: Asaf thanks for the edit. Found it really difficult to write this up. First time using latex properly on this site.

Comment: $\{n\in\mathbb N:a_nb_n=c_nd_n\}=A\cap B$ isn't quite true; that should be $\supseteq$, I think. Argument still works, though.

Comment: Did you mean $a_nc_n=b_nd_n$?

Comment: Comumbus, yes I did. Will edit that now. Thanks for the error spot.

Comment: The reason I said you need $\supseteq$: Consider the case where $a_0=1$, $b_0=2$, $c_0=6$, and $d_0=3$. Then you have $0$ being an element of the LHS and not the RHS, no matter what the other indices ($a_1$ etc.) are.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now to try and show that Hyperreals form an ordered field :P.

Comment: Well, just notice that if $X$ is in the ultrafilter and $Y\supseteq X$ then $Y$ is in the ultrafilter, by definition. After that, basically just use your arguments.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it should be too bad. Since most of the axioms come from the Real numbers anyway. The only thing I'm not sure of is once I've shown it is a field is it sufficent to just show that [a_n]<[b_n] or [b_n]<[a_n] or do I have to show antisymmetric, transtivity also.

Comment: Once you show everything is well-defined, I guess you can just use the transfer principle. Prove the transfer principle and use it.

Comment: In the def'ns of A,B,etc., the layout would be better if the "A=" etc. were included in the  "display" lines.